# how MIPS load an double value into a register?

Tags: mips

in mips assembly there are the instruction (addi) to put an integer value into an register , my question is:

```
addi $t1,$zero,8.9 #MIPS ERROR
```

if I want to put a double value into an register in MIPS which instruction i have to use ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to load floating point immediates is to load them from memory.

In the data section you can define floating point constants, e.g.

```
.data
doubleValue: .double 123.456
floatValue: .float 123.456
```

And then use pseudoinstructions `l.s` (for floats) and `l.d` (for doubles) to load them onto floating point registers., e.g.

```
.text
  l.s $f1, floatValue   # Loads constant 123.456 onto $f1
  l.d $f2, doubleValue  # Loads constant 123.456 onto $f2-$f3
```

---

Alternatively you can load the immediates that encode a floating point number into general purpose registers, and then use `mtc1`/`mtc1.d` to move them to floating point registers. This is tricky in the sense that you have to encode the floating point constant.

For example, say you want to load 123.456 onto a floating point register, you may do this:

```
  li $t1, 0x42f6e979  # 0x42f6e979 is the encoding for 123.456 single precision float
  mtc1 $t1, $f1       # move that float to $f1
```

And if you were to load 123.456 onto a double, you would issue:

```
  li $t2, 0x1a9fbe77  # 0x405edd2f1a9fbe77 is the encoding for 123.456 double
  li $t3, 0x405edd2f
  mtc1.d $t2, $f2     # move that double to $f2-$f3
```

Comment: I build compiler so ...it is very difficult to save all double value in (.data) if I use your way I must to link every double variable with his value ... so hard

Comment: @elisha: I don't fully understand your problem. There is another (tricky) way to load floating point constants directly. See updated answer

Comment: if I use your (tricky) way I must to calculate encoding for every double value i want to put it into register ?

Comment: there are a function in c/c++ to calculate the encoding for a given double number? @gusbro

Comment: @elisha: If you are working with C you don't need a function to get the encoding, you have to "see" the floating point as an integer, e.g: `float something = 123.456;  int encoding = *((int *)&something);`. You may see this tricky again ;)

Answer (score 0):

it is very much similar to the stranded way of writing the operands .
 First difference is that the $f(operand number ) should be used instead of  $t(operand number).

The values cannot be loaded as immediate values , they have to declared in `.data` section .

The floating point registers you use should be even numbers .

Then as you are loading the float value the opcode should be `l.s`.

The `add.d` command should be used as these are double values

for example to add and 10 and 2.5

```
.data 
    float1 : .float 2.5 # declaring the floating values
    float2 : .float 10.0 # declaring the floating values
.text 
 main :

 l.s $f0 , float1 # loading the floating values to regester
 l.s $f2 , float2 # loading the floating values to regester
 add.d $f4 , $f0 , $f2
```